# Best Practice for Budgeting MySQL Database Design

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to find the best solution for my needs. I have a budgeting application that each user will have their own budget which will include potentially hundreds or thousands of budget entries. Initially I thought I would have a table for the users and basic info, and then each user would have their own sql table with all of their budget items held within. However, if the user list grows to hundreds or thousands then I would have a large amount of tables since each user would have their own. I also considered a single table to hold everyone's budget entries but I'm not sure that's the correct solution either.
Any advice? Thank you in advance

Comment: "each user would have their own sql table"...no, this goes against database normalisation principles (which I would guess you either haven't studied or haven't understood, or else you would never propose such a thing). A single table would make much more sense. Then you just have a column containing the user ID, and that has a foreign key relationship back to the User table. If you haven't yet studied relational database design, it would be sensible to do so before attempting to design one.

Comment: sorry, i didn't put my thoughts into the correct wording. I mean the users as a whole would have their own table that would hold them all and their basic info. My  apologies.

Comment: if you already know that, then what's your question? You asked whether each user should have a separate table. The answer is no. Now you claim you always knew that the users should all be in one table.

Comment: In my original question, I stated that I would have a table that holds all of the users, as in the users name, and some basic info. This table would hold ALL of the users. My questions is more about what would be best for the individual budget items. Would it be better to have every users budget items in one table or would it be better for each users budget items to have their own table. I realize that I could have an ID field for the user and link that to the budget items if every persons items were all in the same table. I wasn't clear what the best solution would be in terms of scaling.

Comment: Right I see. But my comment, I thought, made it clear I was talking about a budgets table (hence the reference to a foreign key back the users table). So I was confused when you then defended your idea to have all the users in one table. I think I just didn't quote enough of your question.

Comment: Anyway...you should definitely have all your budgets in one table. It will scale fine as long as you have indexes defined, and sufficient physical resources for your database. Apart from anything else, reporting etc will be impossible if you have a table-per-user. And also writing generic queries which can vary the user ID will be nearly impossible (as changing the table name via a parameter is not possible from an external application). If you design your DB in a properly normalised way that kind of problem doesn't occur. Again, if you'd studied database design you'd never even suggest this.

Comment: Have one table, and see about partitioning. But don't sweat it. By the time you have a user base large enough to be problematic, you'll either be rich enough to pay someone to solve it, or too rich to care.

Comment: For a little perspective on the other comments, understand that tables with millions of rows are routine for modern databases. Performance is going to be dictated by how you index and partition that large table, and designing your tables and queries to avoid outer joins between tables that have millions of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a single table that holds all the budget entries, with a primary key that's referenced by a foreign key in the "users" table, is a good way to go. You can always use something like `select * from users u join budgets b on u.userID = b.userID where userID = xxx` to get the budget items for a particular user.